# jq - remove non-matching fields in "object-array-with-objects"

Tags: json, jq

Given the following JSON-object:

```json
{
  "meta": {
    "data1": {
      "keep": { "key": "value" }
    }
  },
  "detail": {
    "data2": [
      {
        "keep1": "keep1value",
        "keep2": "keep2value",
        "nokeep1": "abc"
      }
    ],
    "data3": [
      {
        "keep1": "keep1value",
        "keep2": "keep2value",
        "nokeep2": { "abc": "def" }
      }
    ]
  },
  "drop" : "this"
}
```

I'm trying to clean it by removing unwanted fields, like "remove", "nokeep1" and "nokeep2".
However objects in the "data2" and "data3" arrays might contain more fields than the example "nokeepX", but will always contain "keep1" and "keep2" which I want to keep.

My desired output is the following JSON:

```json
{
    "meta": { "data1": { "keep": { "key": "value" } } },
    "detail": {
        "data2": [
            {
                "keep1": "keep1value",
                "keep2": "keep2value"
            }
        ],
        "data3": [
            {
                "keep1": "keep1value",
                "keep2": "keep2value"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've managed to remove the "drop" field with this query:
`jq 'def pick($paths): . as $root | reduce ($paths[]|[.]|flatten(1)) as $path ({}; . + setpath($path; $root|getpath($path))); pick([["meta"], ["detail", "data2"], ["detail", "data3"]])'`

However I've been struggling to figure out how to remove the "nokeepX" fields - is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: How did `data2` and `data3` become `data1` and `data2`?

Comment: I messed up trying to create example data.

Comment: Had also mixed the "data1" and "data2" in the query, so fixed that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only a limited set of properties, it could be easier not to remove unwanted fields, but create the output from the required fields only:

```
{
    meta,
    detail: .detail | {
        data2: .data2 | map({ keep1, keep2 }),
        data3: .data3 | map({ keep1, keep2 })
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "meta": {
    "data1": {
      "keep": {
        "key": "value"
      }
    }
  },
  "detail": {
    "data2": [
      {
        "keep1": "keep1value",
        "keep2": "keep2value"
      }
    ],
    "data3": [
      {
        "keep1": "keep1value",
        "keep2": "keep2value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The approach can be combined with dropping certain fields:

```
{
    meta,
    detail: .detail | {
        data2: .data2 | map(del(.nokeep1)),
        data3: .data3 | map(del(.nokeep2))
    }
}
```

producing the same output as above.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide all the concrete paths to `del`:

```bash
del(
  .detail.data2[0].nokeep1,
  .detail.data3[0].nokeep2,
  .drop
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YsJ5Sp41DzR)

Or generalize by e.g. traversing all array items (not just the first) using `[]` without indices:

```bash
del(
  .detail.data2[].nokeep1,
  .detail.data3[].nokeep2,
  .drop
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nW-T4noF7X5)

Or go arbitrarily deep using `..`, and just provide the deepest field names:

```bash
del(.. | objects | .nokeep1, .nokeep2, .drop)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KkA7rUbxwuG)

Output:

```json
{
  "meta": {
    "data1": {
      "keep": "true"
    }
  },
  "detail": {
    "data2": [
      {
        "keep1": "keep1value",
        "keep2": "keep2value"
      }
    ],
    "data3": [
      {
        "keep1": "keep1value",
        "keep2": "keep2value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

For the other way round, you could list all the leaf paths using `paths(scalars)`, filter out those where the deepest level `.[-1]` does `not` match your criteria, and use `delpaths` to remove the remaining leafs:

```bash
delpaths([paths(scalars) | select(
  .[-1] | IN("keep", "keep1", "keep2") | not
)])
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9VRqAFLu1Oz)

Comment: The "nokeepX" was just included example fields, there's more fields as I mentioned, so I was trying to create a query where I just list the fields I want to keep, ie. "keep1" and "keep2".
Is it possible to "invert" your query somehow?

Comment: @lilleng Your question defined the task as "removing unwanted fields, like …" with a list of leaf-level field names. For the other way round, please provide how you define **explicitly** what to keep (given your specific sample data)

Comment: @lilleng I have added a possible interpretation.

Comment: A hopefully better description would be: I only want to keep "keep1" and "keep2" for objects in the "data2" and "data3" arrays, and the "meta" and "detail" fields.

Comment: It solved my issue partly, I see now that my example didn't include nested objects, I removed them to keep the example small and neat ...
I'll update the example data, but here's an [updated demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BbuSN9W5z4y)

Comment: When I combined your latest query with my initial one, I got the desired structure, [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LNDZ6QdZATN)